# How to find the same item in multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, find

If there are more than 1 list with different length, what's the fast way to find out same item in each list?

Comment: If order doesn't matter, the fastest way would be to use a `set` and do a membership check for that particular item. It can't get any faster than that IMO without putting in additional pains.

Comment: You may want to provide some more information regarding the context of your question. You'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

s = set.intersection(*map(set, a))
```

`s` is a set with a single element `3`.